# Почему не работает событие click в данном примере?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему не работает событие `click` при нажатии второго раза на класс `btn` ?

```js
$(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr('name') == 'first')
            $(this).replaceWith('<button class="btn" name="second">2</button>');
        else
            $(this).replaceWith('<button class="btn" name="first">1</button>');
    })
})
```

```css
.btn {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn" name="first">1</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'first') 
      $(this).replaceWith('<button class="btn" name="second">2</button>');
    else 
      $(this).replaceWith('<button class="btn" name="first">1</button>');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn" name="first">1</span>
```

Comment: Теперь работает, но перестал работать `this`. Как узнать на каком элементе выполнилось событие?

Comment: @Cristian Это Вы случайно что-то поломали.

Comment: и вправду, я забыл что изменил `.on('click')` на `.click()`. Наверно функция `.click()` не принимает такой параметр.